# Execute code at specific time in react native

Tags: react-native

I want to execute some function of my react native app at certain times, no matter if the app is opened or in background.

For example, execute the function at monday 3:00pm and wednesday 5:00pm

Is it possible to achieve this? Sorry if the question is noob. The alternative is to send a request from server side, but I want to know if is possible from the app side.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is totally no support for background tasks, only for Android bit it is still limited: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/10/25/0-36-headless-js-the-keyboard-api-and-more.html

There is also limitation in React Native, when the app is in the background the js bridge stops getting messages.